# JavaScript Language Reference Manual

Tags: javascript

Is there a complete and a most updated and downloadable JavaScript Language Reference Manual!?

Answer (score 12):

The closest thing to an official documentation is the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Implementors of JavaScript follow this specification.

However, the most widely used and penetrable (reading the spec for quick reference can be daunting) documentation is [JavaScript at Mozilla Documentation Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript). It has a lot of information that is handy for using JavaScript in the browser too.

Comment: +1 for this, and way better than a lot of the horrible references (like w3schools) that you can find online.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ECMA specification is for ECMAScript Language, JS is much broader concept including DOM, all sorts of APIs and so on..

Comment: @valentinas In the browser, the DOM is very important, but technically it's not part of JavaScript the language. Just an API defined by the W3C that JavaScript uses in the browser to interact with the page's contents.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to be a bit of a detective to find all the differences between implementers. Something in IE could be just different enough to break your code but look exactly the same as something in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript is not one *thing*, with a single possible manual. There are different things that people put together under the JavaScript name:

- The [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)
- The different implementations of a JavaScript engine used by browsers, which extend the ECMA standard with new APIs
- Various APIs defined elsewhere, mostly at W3C, such as DOM, HTML5 APIs, other parts that people put under the HTML5 umbrella
- Various serverside engines, like Node.js, which add their own APIs, plus all of the libraries that work with these engines
- Tons of libraries and frameworks that are built on top of the base JavaScript support that browsers offer, like React, Angular, jQuery...

The best reference for what is normally considered JavaScript is indeed the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).